# Is "USB-Drive" a synonym of "USB"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Due to fundamental insecurity of [usb](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb), should we synonymize it with [usb-drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) and make the tag wiki the same for both?

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree: we have 77 tagged [usb-drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) and of the 11 tagged [usb](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb), 6 are definitely to do with USB drives. The other 5 are around the firmware attack.

If we have these set as synonyms, it's not going to adversely impact readability, and could help us.

Answer (score 2):

No, [usb](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) is not the same thing as [usb-drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive).

Most questions about USB something are about removable drives in general, and the fact that they happen to be connected over USB is just a matter of today's dominant technology. Maybe we should synonymize [usb-drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) to [removable-drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removable-drive).

We have a few questions about USB itself or about removable devices in general. I just went and retagged a few [usb](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) questions that were really about USB drives. That still leaves some questions about USB itself, justifying a separate tag.

Comment: I agree USB is a standard. Where-as a USB-drive is a storage device that uses USB to transfer data.